# Do you share your story titles with players?

Tags: gm-techniques, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, story

I've started to taking to naming my stories, even for no other purpose than record keeping. However I've been thinking about sharing the names of the stories with the players.

If you do it do  before or after completion?

If you're running a "multi track" game does that affect when you reveal?

If you tell them in advance how far?

how much does your story title reveal about the story itself? for example "Vampire in the Park" seems like a poor title if you're running a mystery.

Comment: I suggest you rephrase this question so that it is more directed. Right now it stands a good chance of being closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Yes, this is currently a poll.

Comment: @Grubermensch I've reapplied the NWOD tag to this question since it could be significant, and the questions inside already contain NWOD-specific concerns.

Comment: Story, or chapter?

Comment: @Oxinabox in theory *story* and *acts* (acts being a collection of stories). doubt this'll get reopened though as I've no idea how to better word it

Comment: @xenoterracide if you're mainly just interested in finding out how people approach this and the results they get, maybe you should ask a NWOD forum.

Comment: I know the question is closed, but HTH: I love to use titles which have 2 meanings.  As the PCs start to get into it they think it means one thing, but later on it turns out to mean something else.  An easy way to do this is to use a phrase without a subject noun, for example: "Out of the Frying Pan, Into the Fire".  Make the initial story/lead-in about getting someone out of trouble (probably an NPC).  The players think the title is a reference to the NPC, but then a little later on, trouble strikes *them* and they realize they're the ones "in the fire"!